# Evaluate the limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\mathopen{\Big(}\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{1-\cos(4x)}\mathclose{\Big)}^2 $

Tags: limits

I`m trying to evaluate this limit and I need some advice how to do that.
 $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{1-\cos(4x)}\right)^2 $$

What I did so far with no solution is:
$$\frac{1-2\cos(2x)+\cos^2(2x)}{1-2\cos(4x)+\cos^2(4x)}$$

Comment: A LaTeX tip: Trig functions and other functions with "names" should be written upright, so I suggest you use `\sin`, `\cos`, `\log`, etc . to produce $\sin$, $\cos$, $\log$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to worry about the squaring much because $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \left[f(x)\right]^2 = \left[\lim_{x \to a} f(x)\right]^2 $ if the limit exists.

Also, the expansion of $ \cos(ax) $ at $ x = 0 $ is $ 1 - \frac{a^2}{2}x^2 + O\left(x^4\right) $ and hence $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{1 - \cos(4x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x^2 + O \left(x^4\right)}{8x^2 + O\left(x^4\right)} = \frac{1}{4} $$ Hence the final answer is $ \frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: so if its like that : $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \left[f(x)\right]^2 = \left[\lim_{x \to a} f(x)\right]^2 $ I can do L'hopital inside the squaring.

Comment: Yes, L'hospital's rule or series expansion both make sort work of the inner limit.

Comment: It will be : $$\frac{sin(2x)*2*4*2}{sin(4x)*4*4*2} = (\frac{1}{4})^2=\frac{1}{16}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$1 - \cos(x)\sim  \frac{x^2}{2} $when $x\to 0$$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{1-\cos(4x)}\right)^2=(\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{(2x)^2}{2}}{\frac{(4x)^2}{2}})^2=\frac{1}{16}$$

Comment: +$\Large\color{red}{Ⓝⓘⓒⓔ}$ $\Large\color{brown}{Ⓗⓘⓝⓣ}$+@Maisam Hedyelloo

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\cos(2y)=\cos^2(y) - \sin^2(y)=1-2\sin^2(y)$

Comment: and for $1-cos(4x)$ is the same logic just $cos^2(2y)-sin^2(2y)$?

Comment: Indeed; the formula is valid for all $y$; even for $y=2x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{1-\cos(4x)}\right)^2 $$
 $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-(1-2\sin^2x))}{1-(1-2\sin^22x)}\right)^2 $$
 $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{2\sin^2x}{2\sin^22x}\right)^2 $$
 $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin2x}\right)^4 $$

$$\dfrac{1}{16}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin x}{x}}{\dfrac{\sin2x}{2x}}\right)^4 $$
since $$\lim\limits_{a\to 0}\dfrac{\sin a}{a}=1$$
so: $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1\;\;and\;\;\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin 2x}{2x}=1
$$
$$\dfrac{1}{16}\times 1\implies \dfrac{1}{16} $$

Answer (score 0):

Transforming the original expression as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \frac{1-\cos 2x}{1-\cos 4x}\right) ^{2} &=&\left( \frac{1-\cos 2x}{%
(2x)^{2}}\frac{(4x)^{2}}{1-\cos 4x}\frac{(2x)^{2}}{(4x)^{2}}\right) ^{2} \\
&=&\left( \frac{1-\cos 2x}{(2x)^{2}}\frac{(4x)^{2}}{1-\cos 4x}\frac{1}{4}%
\right) ^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
and using the standard limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos u}{u^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
it follows that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{1-\cos 2x}{1-\cos 4x}\right) ^{2}=\left( 
\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{1}\frac{1}{4}\right) ^{2}=\frac{1}{16}.
\end{equation*}
${\bf Remark:}$ What really was used, is not the standard limit itself! It is the
fact that the limit $(1)$ exists and is a finite number different from zero,
say $L\neq 0.$ So, 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{1-\cos 2x}{1-\cos 4x}\right) ^{2}=\left(
L\cdot \frac{1}{L}\cdot \frac{1}{4}\right) ^{2}=\frac{1}{16}.
\end{equation*}
If, instead the standard limit, one takes 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{u-\sin u}{u^{3}}=\frac{1}{6}\ (=L\neq 0)
\end{equation*}
then the same idea provides
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{2x-\sin 2x}{4x-\sin 4x}\right) ^{2}=\frac{1%
}{64}.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
since
$\cos(2z)
=1-2\sin^2(z)
$
or
$1-\cos(z)
=2\sin^2(z/2)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{1-\cos(bx)}
&=\frac{2\sin^2(ax/2)}{2\sin^2(bx/2)}\\
&=\frac{\sin^2(ax/2)}{\sin^2(bx/2)}\\
&=\left(\frac{\sin(ax/2)}{ax/2}\right)^2
\left(\frac{bx/2}{\sin(bx/2)}\right)^2
\frac{(ax/2)^2}{(bx/2)^2}\\
&=\left(\frac{\sin(ax/2)}{ax/2}\right)^2
\left(\frac{bx/2}{\sin(bx/2)}\right)^2
\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}
= 1
$,
$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{1-\cos(bx)}
=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2
$.

For $a=2$ and $b=4$,
$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2
=\left(\frac{2}{4}\right)^2
=\frac14
$.